# How exit a BEGIN loop in Forth?

Tags: break, forth, flow-control

In many languages there is the BREAK statement, which allows you to escape an iterative cycle.

I can't find a word to escape a BEGIN-AGAIN or BEGIN-UNTIL cycle in Forth

I want to implement this code

```
def x():
     for i in range(10):
         print(i, end=' ')
         if i == 5:
             print("break", end=' ')
             break
     print("end")
```

that produces

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 break end
```

Try it using EXIT (gforth 0.7.3)

```
: x 0 begin
         dup dup .
         5 = if
             ."break" exit
        then 
        1+ 
        0
     until
     ." end" ;
```

but it never prints "end":

```
x 0 1 2 3 4 5 break ok
```

I understand that EXIT is really a RETURN in disguise, so one alternative is to put the BEGIN-UNTIL segment in a separate word, but I prefer to maintain the code together.

How do you escape a BEGIN cycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, the `break` statement can be used in *any* level of control-flow nesting and it terminates the nearest enclosing loop (if labels are not used).

In standard Forth, only DO-LOOP loop have a similar statement "`leave`":

```
: x ( -- )
  10 0 ?do
    i .
    i 5 = if ." break " leave then
  loop ."  end "
;
```

To terminate a `begin` loop, you can use `while` — but without any nesting, and without specifying any action on termination:

```
: x ( -- )
  0 begin
    dup .
    dup 5 = dup if ." break " then 0=
  while
    1+
  repeat drop
  ." end "
;
```

Another option is to use a quotation and `exit` inside it:

```
: x ( -- )
  0 [: begin
    dup .
    dup 5 = if ." break " exit then
    1+
  again ;] execute drop
  ." end "
;
```

Also, in Forth, other control-flow construct can be defined using the standard ones.
For example, see my [control-flow-curly.fth](https://github.com/ruv/forth-on-forth/blob/master/lib/control-flow-curly.fth). It allows to specify actions on termination the loop as follows:

```
: x ( -- )
  0 repeat{
    dup .
    dup 5 = if-break{ ." break " }
    1+
  }repeat drop ." end "
;
```

Once this file is downloaded, it can be included into a Forth program or system as `include control-flow-curly.fth` (specify an absolute or relative path, if needed), or via command line.

Comment: I think the reason for not having BREAK is that there may be multiple BREAKs, which requires an iterative loop to process them, which is not yet compiled. It can be avoided by defining UNTIL/AGAIN completely in assembler.

Comment: The only reasons are simplicity and traditions. Assembler is not needed at all. For example, there may be multiple `leave`, and in some systems an iterative loop is used to process them ([example](https://github.com/forthy42/gforth/blob/0cd49b40385b32930bce56869c076ba0af2a96a6/kernel/cond.fs#L319)).

Comment: I don't think possible to implement BREAK in portable Forth.

Comment: It's possible, be assured. It's not much more complicated than supporting multiple `if-break{}` in my library.

Comment: @CandidMoe, even `goto` is possible in standard Forth. My implementation (PoC, with some limitations) is available in [goto.fth](https://github.com/ruv/puzzle-in-forth/blob/main/extension/goto.fth).